# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio connection alias

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use Microsoft SMS Studio to connect to more than a few servers and I'm having a hard time keeping them straight based on the server name. Is there a way to name these connections?
For example, in my local Connect Object Explorer I want to name my connection to the server "PRDWXORDV001\PRD,56011" as "West Server" and "DPOWRMNL011\DDR,55543" as "Jimmy's Server".

This is trivial in Oracle SQ Developer and MySQL Workbench ("Connection Name" in both) but seemingly impossible in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Registered servers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers?view=sql-server-ver15) one per connection.

> [Create a New Registered Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-new-registered-server-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> Registered server name
>
> The name you want to appear in Registered Servers. This name does not have to match the Server name box.

Comment: The info that I enter doesn't seem to be persistent. After I click save, then close/reopen the Registered Server Name gets changed back to the Server Name. Argh, that seems like it is the right place though.

Comment: @Jason That is strange: https://www.mssqlforum.com/threads/registered-servers.41/